# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, xmlhttprequest

I face this problem:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8000/scripts/advaced_donwload/advancedUpload/vueupload/store.php.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

This is my code:

```
storeMeta(file) {
    var fileObject = this.generateFileObject(file)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.$http.post('http://localhost:8888/vueupload/store.php', {
        name: file.name
      }).then((response) => {
        fileObject.id = response.body.data.id
        resolve(fileObject)
      }, () => {
        reject(fileObject)
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hello even I am encountering the same issue. I use the files provided in the solution section of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610107/integrate-two-docker-apps-docker-compose-and-docker-run/56616067#56616067.  Please note that I already have the header setup

Comment: Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

your php server must allow `http://localhost:8080` to `POST` resources. this is done in the server configuration.

1. You can either completely disable the CORS on the server, enabling all sources to communicate with your server.
2. Or you can add this header for the server:

   `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080`
3. Or just allow everything

   `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

To do it in on a `PHP` server, it might be something simple like this:

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

if you are using a framework such as laravel or such, check their documentation in the `CORS` sections

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

$id = uniqid(true);


// http_response_code(500)

echo json_encode([

 'data' => [

   'id' => $id

  ]

 ]);

Comment: try to disable `CORS` completely, which php server/framework are you using?